# Accidentally removed all permissions from a site, any way to recover them?

Tags: 2010, permissions, sharepoint-server, auditing

Short of a full restore from backup I mean. Apparently we don't have a current one.

This site has a ton of broken permissions and we don't have a master list of them, so it's going to be difficult to re-do from scratch.

I ran an audit report, but do not understand the data I got, or know if it's even going to be helpful.  This is a snippit of the audit, one of the removed permissions events.

```
<roleid>-1</roleid><principalid>1018</principalid><scope>AE3212C4-E81B-42C2-B35B-C0DA83245BEE</scope><operation>ensure removed</operation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way to restore the permission, is from backup. There is no OOTB way to restore the permission only.

You mentioned you don't have the latest backup, try to recover the site with different name or different farm from old backup so that dont overwrote the current content.

The from restored site compare the permission and fix it. that's what maximum you can do it.